# Can you directly measure capacitance with some device? I've never heard of a capacity-meter

Tags: capacitance

Can you measure capacitance or is it inferred from other means? For example measuring voltage and discharging and measuring again..
I looked up the equation c=q/v and realized there being a q value you can't just use the voltage so now I'm thinking my proposed method wouldn't even work.

Comment: The method I have my students use in lab is to charge it then discharge it in series with a resistor and measure the time-constant. Whether that is "direct" or not I'll leave to philosophers.

Comment: They are called "LCR Meters". (For Inductance, Capacitance, Resistance).

Comment: It's not uncommon for a multimeter to measure capacitance as well as voltage, current and resistance.

Comment: A multimeter with a capacitance-meter mode is pretty cheap nowadays.  I paid ten or twenty dollars for the last few I bought; [here's a different one](https://www.amazon.com/Dr-Meter-Multimeter-Continuity-Capacitance-Resistance/dp/B00Y1VWM5A/).

Answer (score 1):

The usual instruments to measure capacitances are AC impedance bridges (also called LCR meters). There are handheld and tabletop models. See [Impedance Brigdes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCR_meter#Bridge_circuits)

Comment: Some brief discussion of the working principle would be good.

Comment: @DanielSank - If you follow the link, you will find it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mention, the common way of measuring capacitance is by timing charge / discharge cycles.

It would also be possible to measure it by make a low pass or high pass filter and checking the attenuation of a signal of known frequency.

In general, however, capacitance meters do exist. Some higher-end handheld multi-meters include theses. There are also desktop varieties.